# Programmatically made button destroying itself

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make a button that is programmatically created and when clicked it can destroy itself (and other programmatically made objects).
This is the sub that is called to create the button (alongside two other textboxes ive removed from this code)

```
Public Sub createProduct(i As Integer)
'Creating the button to be able to Delete the product
'i is used as a way to keep track of each row of products
        Dim DeleteProduct As Button = New Button
        With DeleteProduct
            .Size = New Size(20, 20)
            .Location = New Point(240, 50 + (i * 25))
            .Text = New String("-")
            .Name = "btnRemoveProduct" + i.ToString
            UserButtons.Add(DeleteProduct)
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(DeleteProduct)
        AddHandler DeleteProduct.Click, AddressOf DeleteProductButton

    End Sub
```

Which links the button to this code

```
    Friend Sub DeleteProductButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
```

However, I can't find any way to be able to refer to the button (and the other textboxes) in the DeleteProductButton sub, and therefore can't delete them once the button is pressed.

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, Button).Dispose()`

Comment: If i also have a programmatically made textbox (called txtProductName1) in the createProduct sub, how would I go about adding that to the DeleteProductButton sub so that its also deleted when the button is pressed?

Comment: If you have different Controls that work as a unit, they all come and go together, then you need a UserControl, not *sparse* Controls.

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, IDisposable).Dispose()` for different disposable objects, Button, TextBox...etc.